# SAS libref not recognized in macro loop

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've run into an odd SAS quirk that I can't figure out - hopefully you can help.

I have a simple macro loop that imports CSV files and for some reason if I use a libref statement in the "out=" part of the import procedure, SAS doesn't recognize the libref as a valid name. But if I use the same libref in a data step, it works just fine.

The specific error it gives is: "ERROR: "TESTDB." is not a valid name."

I'd like to figure this out because I work with pretty big files and want to avoid reading through them more times than is necessary.

Here's the code that works, with some comments in it. I got around the issue by reading in the files, then writing them to permanent SAS datasets in a second step, but ideally I'd like to import the files directly into the "TESTDB" library. Any idea how to get SAS to recognize a libref in the "out=" statement of the import procedure?

```
libname testdb "C:\SAS test"; 
%let filepath = C:\SAS test\;

%macro loop(values); 
    %let count=%sysfunc(countw(&values)); 
    %do i = 1 %to &count; 
        %let value = %qscan(&values,&i,%str(,));
        proc import datafile = "&filepath.&value..csv" 
            out = &value dbms=csv replace; getnames=yes;
                     /*"out=testdb.&value" in the line above does not work*/
        run; 
        data testdb.&value; set &value; run; 
                 /*here the libref testdb works fine*/
    %end; 
%mend; 
%loop(%str(test_a,test_b,test_c));
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

john

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use something other than a comma as the delimiter character for your list of files?

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of the log with mprint and symbolgen options turned on?

Comment: Why are you using %QSCAN()? Are there characters in the filenames that need quoting?  Also instead of using commas as the delimiter in the macro variable VALUES use something like | (pipe) that is invalid in a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
out=testdb.%unquote(&value)
```

Sometimes the macro language does not unquote values automatically. With result that the extra quoting characters introduced by a quoting function (%qscan %str %bquote %superq etc) cause problems.

Comment: This fixes the problem.  The %str is quoting the value (invisible bit twiddling) and proc import does not recognize the text as being what the human eye sees.  Unquoting removes the bit twiddling.  The text of &value looks the same either way, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Strange error. I am not able to pin it. My guess is that it has something to do with how the *value* macro variables are being created. When I moved the *value* variable creation to a data step and used [Call Symputx](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1nexcs36ctqk5n11uao7k9myz7y.htm), it works.

```
%macro loop(files); 
    /* Create macro variables for files.*/
    data _null_;
        count = countw("&files.",",");
        call symputx("count",count,"L");
        do i = 1 to count;
            call symputx(cats("file",i),scan("&files.",i,","),"L");
        end;
    run;

    /* Read and save each CSV as a sas table. */
    %do i=1 %to &count.;
        proc import datafile = "&filepath.&&file&i...csv" 
            out = testdb.&&file&i. dbms=csv replace; getnames=yes;
        run; 
    %end;
%mend; 

%loop(%str(test_a,test_b));
```